# asp.net how to store more than 2 columns from database in checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, datasource, checkboxlist

When I connect some data source to checkboxlist I can define attributes:

`DataTextField="column1" DataValueField="column2"`

Then I can use in cs file `.Text` and `.Value` Properties respectively.

Columns 1 and 2 are taken from some sql select instruction.

Is there any way to store more than that 2 columns from database.

Something like `CustomDataField="column3"` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the builtin properies of DropDownList there is no way to store more than 2 columns from database.The properties like DataTextField,DataValueField  of DDl are defined in ListControl class of System.Web.dll.